# Configure ElasticSearch Cloud in Spring Boot

Tags: spring-boot, elasticsearch, aws-elasticsearch

I have ES 6.4.3 installed on my local machine as `spring-boot-starter-parent` version `2.1.6.RELEASE` supports this only. I have [THIS](https://github.com/adityajavadeveloper/ElasticSearchPOC/tree/master/ELK_Data_JPA) project working on the local machine.

Now I have signed up for 14 days trial on ES cloud. And want to configure the same in my application. I am confused on how to do this. Tried googling but no help. One thing I want to bring to your notice that, ES cloud offered me ES 6.8.X

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.6.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.elk</groupId>
    <artifactId>ELK_Data_JPA_PCF</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>ELK_Data_JPA_PCF</name>
    <description>Demo project for ELK</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <maven-jar-plugin.version>3.1.1</maven-jar-plugin.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-elasticsearch</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
            <version>2.6.1</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
            <version>2.6.1</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- cloud.elastic.co security support -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.elasticsearch.client</groupId>
            <artifactId>x-pack-transport</artifactId>
            <version>6.4.3</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-snapshots</id>
            <name>Spring Snapshots</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/snapshot</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-milestones</id>
            <name>Spring Milestones</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>

        <!-- This repository is used to test with x-pack -->
        <repository>
            <id>elastic-download-service</id>
            <name>Elastic Download Service</name>
            <url>https://artifacts.elastic.co/maven/</url>
            <releases>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </releases>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>

    </repositories>

    <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>spring-snapshots</id>
            <name>Spring Snapshots</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/snapshot</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </pluginRepository>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>spring-milestones</id>
            <name>Spring Milestones</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>

</project>
```

application.properties:

```
spring.data.elasticsearch.cluster-name=ElasticSearch
spring.data.elasticsearch.cluster-nodes=d78156dfd13c4820aa01119948b9c3fb.ap-southeast-1.aws.found.io:9243
```

I am getting below error.

```
failed to load elasticsearch nodes : org.elasticsearch.client.transport.NoNodeAvailableException: None of the configured nodes are available: [{#transport#-1}{7JBFgKOeQjuFczeTe8qCNw}{d78156dfd13c4820aa01119948b9c3fb.ap-southeast-1.aws.found.io}{13.250.75.109:9243}]
```

Can anyone point me to guide where i can connect ES Cloud using `spring-boot-starter-data-elasticsearch` dependency and not High level client.